# Slim Framework API - how to configure .htaccess file for multiple .php's storing API

Tags: php, mysql, angular, api, slim

im building a crud api for a library system using the slim framework and angular .. but in my api folder i want to multiple .php files.. for example authors.php, publishers.php etc etc i have authors crud system working and ive rewritten it for publishers.php.. but it wont find my database records and is not giving any errors.. i have a strong feeling its my .htaccess file.. but im not sure how to configure it for multiple .php files

this is my current .htaccess .. any help at all would be appreciated as im a newbie to all of these technologys

```
# RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ authors.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: But why, when you have Slim?  [Router](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/router.html)

Answer (score 1):

[Angular application deployment configuration](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#production-servers):

> Apache: add a rewrite rule to the .htaccess file as shown
> (https://ngmilk.rocks/2015/03/09/angularjs-html5-mode-or-pretty-urls-on-apache-using-htaccess/):
>
> ```
> RewriteEngine On
>     # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
>     RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
>     RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
>     RewriteRule ^ - [L]
>     # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
> RewriteRule ^ /index.html
> ```